# I get "operation cannot be completed" when i try to open visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi I am getting the operation cannot be completed error when i tried to open Visual studio 2010. Previous to that I was trying to install web platform and didnt install but that is all I did...anyone have suggestions...i tried restart my pc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `devenv /setup`, `devenv /resetsettings`, or `devenv /resetuserdata`.  *Important:* only try the last two as a last resort since they will reset your settings.

Assuming you're on a 32-bit OS, `devenv` is available from the command-line at `\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` or from the VS command prompt.